# Cannot remove wireless network profile even though admin account is used

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

On my windows computer which is connected to a company domain.
I have problems with the wireless networking. First of all the computer fails to connect.
Second of all I cannot remove the network from the list of wireless profiles.

The properties window simply claims that "This network is administered by the Administartor Account". I am currently logged in as the local administrator. I have also tried creating a new admin account and still get the same problem when trying to remove the network.

My computer has only the microsoft security essentials antivirus and some VMWare+virtual box connections that I can figure might interfere, but disabling realtime protection has not helped me on this. I also cannot delete the virtual network adapters from the control panel / network adapters...

Answer (score 0):

your network settings will be enforced by Group Policy.
There are a few registry hacks that will let you remove the network, but it will be reapplied next time logging in to the domain.

Comment: Could you please describe these hacks?